# How to keep same url path for two different pages using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change my original page of the website after the user takes a premium plan but the URL path remains the same.

If the user is not premium then my website showing URL path: `www.mydomain.com/user-545` (Original Page - www.mydomain.com/page1.php)

But after user taking my premium plan, I need to remain the URL path same `www.mydomain.com/user-545` but need to change my Original Page - `www.mydomain.com/page2.php`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show you code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use the condition based include on the url page  to include the relevant page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up a URL mask.

In your htaccess file, you'll add something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user-545/?$ /page2.php
```

Or you might want to set up a proxy as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106854/1195615).

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve the goal doing a trick. Set cookie, for example, `user_logged_in` when a user is logged in and remove when a user logged out. And then check if the user is logged in, direct the user to the `page2.php` otherwise, `page1.php` setting `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` using `.htaccess` file by checking whether this cookie `user_logged_in` exists or not.

Make sure **rewrite module** is on. And then set up `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` as the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user_logged_in [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?user-[0-9]+$ /page1.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user_logged_in [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?user-[0-9]+$ /page2.php

// Other rules
```

**Note: You must use crytographically secure cookie in this case.**

Comment: This is not a very good idea, unless your cookie is also cryptographically protected somehow. Remember, the cookie **is controlled by the user**. To work in htaccess you need the cookie (its name) to stay the same, so if the *content* also stays the same or is irrelevant, then once the mechanism is known, anyone can get himself promoted to "premium". So the *content* of the cookie needs to be validated server side. And if you need to do server side validation anyway, why not do *only* server validation?

Comment: Yup! you're right! I forgot to mention that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do that in .htaccess? Would it not be simpler to do it in PHP?

- remove the session start code from page1 and page2 (it is probably the same)
  and move to 'session-start.php'
- (optional) you can move most common code from page1 and page2 into session-start.php
- rename page1 to normal.php
- rename page2 to premium.php
- create new page1.php:

  require 'session-start.php';
  if (array_key_exists('premium', $_SESSION)) {
      if ($_SESSION['premium']) {
          include 'premium.php';
          exit();
      }
  }
  include 'normal.php';

You're done.